# Problems playing videos

Tags: codecs, video-player

When I open video files (mp4, mkv, avi) in default Ubuntu 17.10 app ("Videos") I get messy picture with little color squares and after few seconds it totally freezes my screen, so I must restart computer. Probably some codecs missing...

How to check what's wrong and fix it? Thank you.

Graphic card: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
ubuntu-restricted-extras installed
system updated and upgraded

Comment: Please help us help you: 1. What graphics chip/card is there in the computer? 2. Have you installed the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`? 3. Is your system updated and upgraded (up to date with all program packages?

Comment: If the `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` package is installed try removing it, i.e `sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi` then log out/in or reboot

Comment: @doug, Please make an answer from your helpful comment :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If seeing these symptoms with Totem the 1st. thing to check is whether gstreamer1.0-vaapi package is installed. If so removing it can take care of the problem.
This command will suffice to check & if installed remove.

`sudo apt-get purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

There have been continuing issues regarding that plugin since 14.04, for the most part they've been resolved in 18.04 though some hardware could  still experience the video degradation.