# Video player in 18.04 shows a psychedelic mixture instead of a clear video

Tags: 18.04, totem

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with the restricted extras. I've also installed virtually all the GStream packages in an attempt to fix this problem. Whenever I try to play an mp4 I get a mixture of psychedelic colors. I can make out movement in the videos, but I cannot discern features. I do not have this problem with another Linux I installed.

My computer runs an AMD processor with R7 Radeon graphics.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Have you tried any other video player beside Totem like MPV?

Comment: Yes, I've tried MPV and Parole. The problem appears to be only with Totem. I like Totem, and I can't understand whether this is a bug in Totem or a problem with my system. It did not happen on earlier versions of Totem though that was on a different computer.

Comment: There is something wrong with the video driver. I found an AMD driver for 16.04 on the AMD site, and while the driver would not fully install (wrong kernel) parts of it did install and bam! The video problem cleared up. I don't feel comfortable using a driver not for my version of Linux so I removed it, but now I'm back to the psychedelic mess.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem when playing a MP4 video, totem/gnome-videos displays a purplish corrupted video output and I have done the following:

From the terminal `sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

I have done a test and yes, the problem has been fixed now I can see the video correctly.

So the problem is `gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you! That did it! But now I'm having a problem with the video hesitating/haulting every few seconds. Audio is fine though. Probably did it before but I couldn't see it due to the problem I was having.

Comment: yes, same problem here but only when it is not full screen. That is when I look at something in full screen works well.  it's very  strange and at the moment I have not found anything.

Comment: You are right! Thanks. In full screen mode there is no hesitation or jerking. I didn't notice that before ... just assumed the behavior would be the same in either mode. That is really weird. What's even weirder is that I made a new non-admin account and Totem under that account doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Wow, I just jump into the same problem today.

Comment: Also suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026178/problems-playing-videos but syntax of: 
**`sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`**