# Video (Totem) wont play DVD's while others (VLC) can

Tags: 18.04, video, dvd, multimedia, totem

So a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 that's been updated and had the appropriate packages and repositories installed as outlined [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.en) I've also installed VLC and Handbrake handbrake via an up to date repository [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-git-snapshots), as well as running the...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

command. However the Video program (Totem) launches, then immediately crashes upon selecting the button in Nautilus.

[image]

So what have I missed? I can select .mkv files and they play just fine in  Videos (Totem), also DVD's will play just fine using VLC and even Windows programs used under wine. Have I forgotten something? It's been a few years since I've done a new install and even wine required a fix to make .desktop links to launch .exe with wine. Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this on 18.10 with:

```
$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

Hope this works for 18.04, too?

Answer (score 0):

After reading multiple posts on 18.04 and Totem **not working** ..

If found these:

- [Video player in 18.04 shows a psychedelic mixture instead of a clear video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030257/video-player-in-18-04-shows-a-psychedelic-mixture-instead-of-a-clear-video)
- [Problems playing videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026178/problems-playing-videos)

This worked for me:

**`sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`**