# Totem stopped playing videos correctly after upgrade from 18.10>19.04 (Dell Optiplex 9010)

Tags: dell, video-player, 19.04, totem

Just curious if there's anything I could do about this (Is there a setting I can mess with??). I used Totem for the longest time (from 18.04>18.10 at least) and it is my preferred video player for Ubuntu. However, since my upgrade, half of the videos (or so) I try to play end up looking like this [image]

Pretty sure this is a distro-version-wide bug, so if it is sorry for asking. I've been using Smplayer and it's been working just fine, but I'd appreciate any info, thanks

Comment: See if this package is installed, it's presence can cause issues for some hardware.. `sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`  will remove if it's installed..

Comment: @doug Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: As suggested worked this is a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026178/problems-playing-videos/1026517#1026517